# I can't download Xcode Simulator for old iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The minimum iOS version of my project is selected as 11 but I cannot download the simulator. I searched but couldn't find a solution. What should I do?

Available downloadable simulators:

[image]

I chose the minimum iOS version as 11.

Minimum iOS deployment:

[image]

I guess I can't even install iOS 12.4 because I'm using macOS Ventura.

[image]

Comment: It's "linked" to the XCode version that have their own "lower supported version".

Comment: Are you telling me to downgrade xcode? @Larme

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the earlier SDK version for which you want to download the simulators listed among your options, then you cannot download that SDK for use with this version of Xcode on this system.

Comment: What do you think is the solution?

Comment: Don't try to support really old systems. :)

Comment: Actually, it should support iOS 12.4 - 16.1 versions, but I have a minimum of iOs 13.7...

Comment: That doesn't change anything about what I've said.